# Identifying a Star Trek TNG episode by text passage occuring in Carbon Based Lifeforms song "Neurotransmitter"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

[Carbon Based Lifeforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_Based_Lifeforms), an ambient music duo, sometimes embed text passages in their music, taken from various sources. [This website](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Carbon_Based_Lifeforms:Neurotransmitter) claims that a French text passage in the song "Neurotransmitter" is taken "From Star Trek, the Next Generation". The passage translates to:

> It's not a hallucination.
>   It is not a dream.
>   There is a real phenomenon, physical and measurable, lurking on board.
>   Maybe you could help me identify it?

I wonder whether it really is taken from an TNG episode and if so, from which.

Comment: What about the forest?

Comment: Nope. Guess again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Yes.

From the episode [*Remember Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_Me_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) (Season 4 Episode 5):

> CRUSHER: It's not a delusion. It is not a dream. There is a physical, measurable phenomenon at work here. Perhaps you could help me to identify it.
>
> <sub>[transcript link](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/179.htm)</sub>

After many different combinations of search terms on Google, I finally found it by searching for `not a dream real "on board" "identify it" site:http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen`.

Comment: Upvoted for including the appropriate search phrase.

Answer (score 26):

### "[Remember Me](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Remember_Me_(episode))"

From TNG's fourth season, the episode involves Doctor Crusher being trapped in a slowly decaying reality; the line is modified from the following exchange (emphasis mine):

> **Crusher: It's not a delusion. It is not a dream. There is a physical, measurable phenomenon at work here. Perhaps you could help me to identify it.**
>
> **Picard:** How?
>
> **Crusher:** I'd like to use the ship's computer to monitor your life functions.
>
> **Picard:** Until I disappear.
>
> **Crusher:** It will happen.
>
> <sup>*Star Trek: The Next Generation* Season 4 Episode 6: "Remember Me"</sup>

Comment: Ninja'd! :-) Nice job.